# Scrolling Pictures With links - Blank First Image?

Tags: loops, settimeout, banner, timedelay

I am having an issue where I have a scrolling image with links which works perfectly except that before the first image shows there is nothing for 5 seconds. Can anyone help?

Thank you

HTTP:

```html
<script>
        var links = ["link1","link2","link3"];
        var images = ["img1","img2","img3"];
        var i = 0;
        var renew = setInterval(function(){
            if(links.length == i){
                i = 0;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("bannerImage").src = images[i]; 
            document.getElementById("bannerLink").href = links[i]; 
            i++;

        }
        },5000);
        </script>



<a id="bannerLink" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href); return false;">
<img id="bannerImage" width="15%" alt="" style="position:fixed; right:2.5%; border-style: none; top:47%">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that the 10 people who viewed this decided to comment, so I assume you are just as clueless.

After much frustration I found that if you just simply put in src="img1" into the img tag

and

src="link1" into the link tag

it solved all my problems.